# Setup SMTP server to use it in Send mail task from SSIS?

Tags: ssis, smtp

I want to send the email using Send mail task, I have already tried using script task and it was successful
Do not answer like use script task etc. I have already used it and it worked for Gmail.
I am learning send mail task and I have created SMTP connection manager , I don't know how can i setup the SMTP server using windows authentication so that the server name I can give in the SMTP connection Manager.
I an expecting answer to the question "How can i setup the SMTP server which if any public email allows setting up SMTP server using windows authentication on my local box so that I can use it in Send mail task ?"

Any help in this regard is appreciated...

Also do not answer like your company will provide that , I myself want to setup it and use it .

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a new smtp connection first: see this link for more info: [ssis mail](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.al/2013/08/sending-mail-within-ssis-part-1-send.html)

Comment: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_BGpY11nMok/UfQsasxnodI/AAAAAAAACXA/Dwk2BoJoL-c/s1600/sendmail13.jpg